# PHP date returns wrong day value

Tags: php, date

I am creating a new Date period as an array. I loop through the dates and I am trying to get the Day value as string

```
<?php
$period = new DatePeriod(
      new DateTime('27-02-2019'),
      new DateInterval('P1D'),
      new DateTime('03-03-2019')
    );

    foreach( $period as $date) { $array[] = $date->format('d-m-y');
      $newDate = $date->format('d/m/Y'); // for example
      echo "The date is " .$newDate." ";
      $timestamp = strtotime($newDate);
      $day = date('l', $timestamp);
      echo "The day is ".$day." \n"; ?>
      <br>
    <?}?>
```

On my echo, I get the correct date but it gives the wrong day.

Any idea why it behaves like that? This is what it returns 
[image]

Comment: Why are you mixing `DateTime()` and `strtotime()`? `DateTime()` already does everything you need.

Comment: You just need to use $date->format('l') to get the date. No need to convert it to a timestamp first.
The bug is actually that you're using d/m/Y. When you're using slashes, the US format m/d/y is assumed. You need to use m/d/Y if you want to keep your code like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By combining `DateTime()` with `strtotime()` you opened yourself up to a common error when working with dates. By trying to convert a date using dd/mm/yyyy format you are assumed to be using US date format which is mm/dd/yyyy which is incorrect. So `28/02/2019` becomes `The second day of the 28th month in the year 2019` which is not what you intended.

You can avoid this entirely by continuing to use `DateTime()` all the way through and avoiding unnecessary format conversions. It's even less code!

```
<?php
$period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('27-02-2019'),
    new DateInterval('P1D'),
    new DateTime('03-03-2019')
);

foreach( $period as $date) { $array[] = $date->format('d-m-y');
    $newDate = $date->format('d/m/Y'); // for example
    echo "The date is " .$newDate." ";
    $day = $date->format('l');
    echo "The day is ".$day." \n"; ?>
    <br>
<?}?>
```

Output:

```
The date is 27/02/2019 The day is Wednesday
The date is 28/02/2019 The day is Thursday
The date is 01/03/2019 The day is Friday
The date is 02/03/2019 The day is Saturday
```

Comment: I would add that in most cases `new DateTime()` should not be used for parsing either, in favor of `DateTime::createFromFormat()`.